# No bootable device found on new laptop

Tags: boot, 20.04, hard-drive, dell, devices

I hope you are well,
I have a problem that I personally can't figure out, here I am using a Dell Inspiron 6450 computer in which I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 as the operating system.
I have a new HP Probook computer in which I would like to use the hard disk in my old computer, the problem occurs when I take my main hard disk in which Ubuntu 20.04 is installed and I put it in my new computer, at startup I get this message :
No bootable device found - insert boot disk and press any key.

While in the BIOS settings, the hard disk appears as installed, and is in first position in the boot order.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Does the Ubuntu disk use UEFI or legacy?

Comment: Ubuntu disk use UEFI